# Why is there no proper map for the topologist sine curve?

Tags: analysis, submanifold

**EDIT:** Due to some confusion in the comments as to what my question is, note the following is an almost (modified to dimension 1) direct quote from Leon Simon's book on Geometric Measure Theory:

Let $M$ be a 1 dimensional $C^1$ submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^2$. In other words, $M \subset \mathbb{R}^2$, and for each $(x,y) \in M$, there are open sets $V \subset \mathbb{R}$, $W \subset \mathbb{R}^2$, with $(x,y) \in W$ and a $1-1$, $C^1$ map $\psi: V \to W$ with

$$ \psi(V) = W \cap M$$

where $\psi $ is **proper** (if $K\subset W$ compact, then $\psi^{-1} K$ is compact in $V$.), and $D \psi(x,y) \neq 0$ for each $(x,y) \in V$.

The condition that $\psi$ is proper includes examples like

$$M = \{ (x, \sin 1/x): x >0 \}$$

but eliminates examples such as

$$M = \{ 0 \} \times (-1,1) \cup \{ (x, \sin 1/x): x >0 \}.$$

END QUOTE

Note no $\psi$ is specified.

**Question:** Why is  there a proper $\psi$ for $$M = \{ (x, \sin 1/x): x >0 \}$$ but there is no proper $\psi$ for
$$M = \{ 0 \} \times (-1,1) \cup \{ (x, \sin 1/x): x >0 \}?$$

I understand that the second example is not a submanifold because its not pathconnected, and homeomorphisms preserve path-connectedness. What does $\psi$ being proper have to do with it?

Comment: You ask "Why is $\psi$ proper", but no $\psi$ has been specified for either of your two examples of $M$.

Comment: @LeeMosher Correct, that is my question

Comment: In your second example, $M$ is not a $C^1$ submanifold of ${\bf R}^2$.

Comment: I guess the author was saying that for any $\psi$ with the given conditions, $\psi$ will be proper for the  first $M$ but not for the second

Comment: @coudy Is it not $C^1$?

Comment: For $(0,0)$, you can't find a $\psi$ as requested in the definition of a submanifold.

Comment: The question is: If we drop the assumption "proper", why is the second space a submanifold?

Comment: @PaulFrost I see. Perhaps there is a typo in the book..?

Comment: @user35687 No typo. I think you misunderstood  the author. He does not consider a specific $\psi$, but wants to say that the second space (which certainly does not deserve to be called a submanifold) admits non-proper $\psi$ at all points, but **no** proper $\psi$ at all points.

Comment: @PaulFrost I understand that the second space is not a submanifold because its not pathconnected, so we cant find a homeomorphism from $R$ to $M$. So can we indeed find non-proper $\psi$ at $(0,0)$? $\psi $ is assumed to be a homeomorphism

Comment: @user35687 You should edit your question. Comments are not suitable for that purpose.

Comment: @PaulFrost The question already says $\psi$ is 1-1 and $C^1$

Comment: @user35687 In my comments I tried to say that your question does not make sense in its present form. I suggest that you make an edit to clarify what the question is. Certainly not "Why is $\psi$ proper" since no $\psi$ is specified.  Note that there are already two close votes (not from  me). Also edit the title.

Comment: @PaulFrost I edited it, but there are not much more details to write, its pretty much a direct quote from the book. I am not understanding something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $M = \{ (x, \sin 1/x): x >0 \}$ and all points of $M$ we can take the proper map
$$\psi : (0,\infty) \to (0,\infty) \times  \mathbb R, \psi(x) = (x, \sin 1/x) .$$

For $M' = \{ 0 \} \times (-1,1) \cup M$ consider any point $p \in M'$. We want to show that there are open sets $V \subset \mathbb{R}$, $W \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ with $p \in W$ and an injective $C^1$ map $\psi: V \to W$ such that $\psi(V) = W \cap M'$ (we do not require $\psi$ to be proper).

Define $W = \mathbb R^2$ (which is an open neighborhood of $p$) and $V = (-2,0) \cup (0,\infty)$ (which is an open subset of $\mathbb R$). The map
$$\psi : V \to W, \psi(x) = \begin{cases} (0,x+1) & x \in (-2,0) \\  (x, \sin 1/x) & x \in (0,\infty) \end{cases}$$
is an injective $C^1$ map such that $\psi(V) = M' = W \cap M'$.

It is not proper.

Consider the compact set $K = \{(0,0)\} \cup \{(1/ n\pi,0) : n \in \mathbb N \}$. Then $\psi^{-1}(K) = \{-1\} \cup \{1/ n\pi : n \in \mathbb N \}$ which is not compact.

This shows that if we drop the assumption that $\psi$ must be proper, $M'$ would be a submanifold of $\mathbb R^2$.